# Calling constructor for type „-.l1lilliIililI” compatible with set limits of linking caused exception

Tags: c#, xaml

I tried to run my application as release and following error apeard. I have seen threads on stacoverflow with XMLserializer, but it didn't help. What is the class **-.l1lilliIililI**, where does it come from? Under debug mode application can be run without any problems. Message is somehow translated in topic.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
Message=Wywołanie konstruktora dla typu „-.l1lilliIililI” zgodnego z określonymi ograniczeniami wiązania spowodowało wyjątek.
Source=PresentationFramework
LineNumber=0
LinePosition=0
StackTrace:
   w System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   w System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   w System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   w System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   w System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   w System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   w System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   w System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   w System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   w MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   w System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   w System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   w System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   w System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   w System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   w MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   w MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   w System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   w MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   w System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   w MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   w MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   w System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   w System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   w System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   w System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   w System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   w System.Windows.Application.Run()
   w  .()
   w System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   w System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   w Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   w System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   w System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: System.ArgumentException
   Message=Identyfikator ' ' nie jest zgodny z CLS.
Nazwa parametru: ident
   Source=System.Xml
   ParamName=ident
   StackTrace:
        w System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.CheckValidIdentifier(String ident)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.EscapeKeywords(String identifier, CodeDomProvider codeProvider, StringBuilder sb)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t, Type[] parameters, Int32 index, StringBuilder sb)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t, Type[] parameters, Int32 index, StringBuilder sb)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.CodeIdentifier.GetCSharpName(Type t)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.get_CSharpName()
        w System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.WriteElements(String source, String enumSource, ElementAccessor[] elements, TextAccessor text, ChoiceIdentifierAccessor choice, String arrayName, Boolean writeAccessors, Boolean isNullable)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.WriteMember(String source, String choiceSource, ElementAccessor[] elements, TextAccessor text, ChoiceIdentifierAccessor choice, TypeDesc memberTypeDesc, Boolean writeAccessors)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.GenerateTypeElement(XmlTypeMapping xmlTypeMapping)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.GenerateElement(XmlMapping xmlMapping)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
        w System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
        w  .[T](String )
        w  .()
        w  .()
        w -.l1lilliIililI.()
        w -.l1lilliIililI..ctor()
   InnerException:
```

Comment: I found something about this strange name on russian webpage, but there is no explenation what it is.

Comment: It is probably just a unique name for a runtime generated class.

Comment: Look at this: http://www.wow-bots.at.ua/forum/10-329-1 - unique class shouldn't cause errors in different apps imho :)

Comment: Unique *within that context*. The name generation algorithm might well be the same across different apps, if they are using the same framework.